# Стилизация скроллбара в декстоп версии google chrome

Tags: css

В проекте настроены стили для скроллбара, но после обновления chroma в его декстопной версии скроллбар стал снова широким. В других браузерах и мобильной версии chroma всё работает. В чем может быть проблема декстопной?

```
html
   scrollbar-color: rgba(81,121,199,.5) rgba(0,0,0,.1)
   scrollbar-width: thin
::-webkit-scrollbar
   width: 5px
   height: 3px
::-webkit-scrollbar-track
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)
   border-radius: 6px
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
    border-radius: 6px
   background-color: rgba(var(--main-color-rgb), 0.4)
```